# dnf: (something) was supposed to be installed but is not!

Tags: yum, rpm, dnf

I see that it is an error that happend here and there for some packages, but I didnt find any solution working for me.

Everything broke down trying to install Jupyter by `dnf install python2-qtconsole python2-jupyter-core`, when I found that python2-urllib3 was giving an error trying to install.
Now whenever I do: `dnf install python2-urllib3`, 
I get:

```
Dependencies resolved.
========================================================================================================================================
 Package                              Arch                        Version                            Repository                    Size
========================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 python2-urllib3                      noarch                      1.22-3.fc27                        updates                      178 k

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 178 k
Installed size: 678 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
python2-urllib3-1.22-3.fc27.noarch.rpm                                                                   78 kB/s | 178 kB     00:02    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                    53 kB/s | 178 kB     00:03     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                1/1 
  Installing       : python2-urllib3-1.22-3.fc27.noarch                                                                             1/1 
Error unpacking rpm package python2-urllib3-1.22-3.fc27.noarch
Error unpacking rpm package python2-urllib3-1.22-3.fc27.noarch
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname: cpio: File from package already exists as a directory in system
python2-urllib3-1.22-3.fc27.noarch was supposed to be installed but is not!
  Verifying        : python2-urllib3-1.22-3.fc27.noarch                                                                             1/1 

Failed:
  python2-urllib3.noarch 1.22-3.fc27                                                                                                    

Error: Transaction failed
```

I tried all these

```
dnf clean all
yum clean all && rpm --rebuilddb
package-cleanup --problems
rpm -e python3-urllib3-1.22-3.fc27.noarch --nodeps
rpm -i python2-urllib3-1.22-3.fc27.noarch.rpm
```

... and I'm losing ideas fast ...

Comment: The question you link to deals with the problem arising from the attempt to create an RPM package and local install it - different, in fact it suggests to remove a symlink while I dont have any symlinks in my problem dir. From what I saw googling, I didnt find anywhere a general solution for a problem that should be dealt with by a `dnf clean all` or `rebuilddb`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be:

```
 cpio: File from package already exists as a directory in system
```

In a fedora VM I have for testing, this path:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname
```

Is actually a directory and installation was successful. So my guess is that you are pulling a corrupted package from that mirror, I was under the impression that fedora did checksums for download packages, I don't really know, if they do then it would be improbable. You can check the package with:

```
rpm --verify $package_name
```

Some ideas:
Change your mirror in `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo` for the section `[updates]`
comment the `metalink`, and provide a `baseurl` with a mirror of your choice, I suggest you to copy the `baseurl` line and then un-comment it so you can restore the repo file to its original state later.

After that, run again `dnf clean all`, `dnf check-update`, `dnf reinstall ...` .
Once you are sure you have a valid package, if dnf is not doing the job, try some extra options for `rpm --install`, like `--force`. I  also noticed you `rpm --erased` the python3 version and not the python2 version which is the issue, but that may be a typo you made when posting the question, check your `$ history` .
That's all I can see without more logs.

Comment: I'm trying but I'm not sure: after commenting the metalink line I tried to find a mirror list - found one at https://admin.fedoraproject.org/mirrormanager/mirrors/Fedora/27 and set a line `metalink=http://fedora.aau.at/linux` but it isnt working

Comment: I did not suggest you to change the metalink variable, but to change and uncomment the **baseurl** variable, please read the answer carefully.
 `baseurl=http://fedora.aau.at/linux/updates/$releasever/$basearch`
Is working fine.

Comment: I edited the last follow-up, I was not done writing when I posted it, read it now.

Comment: sorry, now I see. I did as suggested and dnf still fails, the same for `rpm --force ...`; suggestion: what about deleting /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/ ? Since it explicitely complains about a directory already present, I guess it's that one

Comment: Was the package downloaded again_?

Comment: yes, again by `dnf install python2-urllib3` - while the one installed by rpm is a local one taken from https://fedora.pkgs.org/27/fedora-updates-i386/python2-urllib3-1.22-3.fc27.noarch.rpm.html

Comment: Did you check it is valid? If the package is valid, with that I mean compare the checksum of the rpm file you have to another one from another mirror, It is better if you take this question to a fedora irc channel or a community more experienced with RPM, and fedora itself, fedora is not my main distro. I cannot suggest anything else.
The error is clear, cpio wants to decompress a file, but your file system already has a directory with the same name. The directory is correct, I have the same in the vm I tried.

Comment: I do not know if deleting the files you say will help or just create a mess for the package manager.

Comment: You've been much more helpful than I had the right to ask for - thank you really much!